# Can I use Objective-C library in xcode 6 using swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I am using xcode 6 and I am trying to implement swift language, now I would like to import some external library from github.com such as [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) that using Objectivc-C language, so can I use it with my project that use swift language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. I highly recommend using [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/), a dependency manager which greatly simplify usage of external libraries.

Also read [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77) as it explains how to use objc from swift.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a bridging header under and add it under the project settings.

Include all the obj-c header you want to use in the bridging header and you are ready to go !